# Best way to delete first row from matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I plan on deleting the first row of a matrix multiple times and was wondering what the best/most efficient way of doing this would be.

I know I can do something like this

```
  M(1,:)=[]
```

or

```
M = M(2:end)
```

but I am not sure which is the best way or if there is another better way.

Comment: have you tries checking it out yourself using `tic` `toc` for example?

Comment: I read somewhere that MATLAB stores matrices in a Column-major fashion. If you are able to construct the data transposed, deleting the first column should have somewhat increased performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey just tested those 2 methods with `tic` and `toc` 
This is the code I used:

```
A=rand(100,100000);
tic
a=A(2:end,:);
t1=toc
tic
A(1,:)=[];
t2=toc
```

and this is the result:

```
t1 =

    0.0603    

t2 =

    0.0744
```

If you use longer columns it gets even more obvious:

```
A=rand(10000,100);
t1 =

    0.0083  

t2 =

    0.0124
```

So saving the columns you want to keep seems to be faster.

**Edit**

It was commented that `tic` and `toc` are not "trustworthy" in the millisecond domain so it was recommended to use loops to run the code multiple times. But the **result doesn't change**.

```
A=rand(100,100000);
size_A=size(A);
tic
for k=1:1:100
    A1=A;
    A1=A1(2:end,:);
end
t1=toc
tic
for k=1:1:100
    A1=A;
    A1(1,:)=[];
end
t2=toc
```

this results in:

```
t1 =

    7.5237

t2 =

   15.2234
```

Comment: Your timing is too short to be reliable I think. Try putting it in a loop? My findings for your matrix are actually opposed to yours I think.

Comment: @EJG89 I don't really see why the timing should be too short, after all matlabs advantage is his fast and easy matrix processing and I am using the same datasets for both methods and even when rerunning the program many times the results (not the values but the relation between) doesn't change. If you add loops you are changing the used method drastically.

Comment: It is fast, and that is the problem in timing such processes. Timings like these might incorporate initialization processes. I personally found that using tic toc in the milliseconds range isn't that trustworthy since deviation between tests is quite large. Using loops to time a single occurrence several times effectively creates a larger number of tests therefore increasing the reliability.

Comment: @EJG89 I used your code inside my `tic`, `toc` commands and the result didn't change. So either `tic`,`toc` are not working or you have an error somewhere. I am editing my post right now.

Comment: The document below is literally my code. Of course different processors, version operating system, version matlab, etc. all affect performance.

Comment: @EJG89 i know but as posted (edit) in my post even if I run the code 100 times the time measured by `tic` and `toc` indicate for both examples the same. Naming that the copying is faster. But because my result and yours (at least for your A) don't fit this indicates that sth is not working right, either in mine or your code.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it might be faster to keep what you want. Depending on the dimensions of your matrix however results may vary. Consider the following test case where two matrices are generated, A1, and B1, of dimension 100x100000 and 100000x100. The results are obtained from the profile viewer but tic toc measurements confirmed these results.

```
A1=rand(100,100000);

for ii=1:100
    A=A1;
    A=A(2:end,:);
end

for ii=1:100
    A=A1;
    A(1,:)=[];
end

B1=rand(100000,100);

for ii=1:100
    B=B1;
    B=B(2:end,:);
end

for ii=1:100
    B=B1;
    B(1,:)=[];
end
```

The results clearly show that the first case (keeping what you want on a matrix with lots of columns) is very slow actually.

There is no clear this or that is faster though. You should try to time for your situation!

[image: Timing results]